# Fold in console info message by default in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, console.log

Info messages in my console in Chrome are expanded by default.
As you can see in the image below, they can be very lengthy (look at the scrollbar being tiny and such). But when I fold them in, they don't take up that much space.
I've checked settings and tried to Google this question, but I can't figure out how to have these messages folded in by default. Is it possible?

[image]

Comment: That looks like an error message, not an info message, so I guess this is the intended behavior. You can define a (global) error handler or a logger function that uses console.groupCollapsed, console.error, console.groupEnd.

Comment: The messages disappear when I uncheck "Info" from the dropdown showing "Default levels" in the screenshot above. Or here: http://jmp.sh/HLWNf8D

Comment: Then it sounds like a bug because info messages do not a have a call stack at all.

Comment: Or maybe that `logging.service.js` does something weird like an explicit call to console.group

Answer (score 0):

> I can't figure out how to have these messages folded in by default. Is it possible?

No, there's no setting to collapse all messsages by default.

One possible solution:

If you don't need to see any messages from the script that's causing the long messages, right-click on the script URL > **Filter** > **Hide messages from foo.js**.

[image: example of filtering out scripts]

Right-click anywhere in the **Console** > **Filter** > **Unhide all** to show them again.

Be careful, though! It looks like this option persists across sessions, and there's not much UI to remind you that you've filtered out messages.